# Computer Type and Asset tag merge using PS

Tags: powershell

I wrote out a PowerShell Script to rename my computer, add it to specific OU's and join it to the domain. My question is we have two types of computer Desktop (DT) and Laptop (LT) and we give it an asset tag and I would like for it to ask me to select if it is a desktop or laptop and then ask for the asset tag number and then add the DT or LT in front of the asset tag number as the computer name (sorry if confused) example: DT01234 or LT01235. I will post my code below and bold the area that renames the computer. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Write-Host "Select Desktop or Laptop [1-2] [Default 1]:
1. Desktop
2. Laptop"

$computertype = Read-Host
Write-Host "Please Enter Asset Tag"
$NewCompName = Read-Host
$renamecomputer = $true
if ($NewCompName -eq "" -or $NewCompName -eq $env:COMPUTERNAME) {$NewCompName = $env:COMPUTERNAME; $renamecomputer = $false}
Write-Host "Please enter your desired location [1-7] [Default 1]: 
1. Test
2. Compliance Stations
3. Controls Stations
4. Processing Stations
5. QC Stations
6. Receiving Stations
7. Shipping Stations"
$ou = Read-Host



#$creds = Get-Credential 

function Test-ADCrential{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [pscredential]$Credential
    )
     
    try {
        Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
        if(!$Credential) {
            $Credential = Get-Credential -EA Stop
        }
        if($Credential.username.split("\").count -ne 2) {
            throw "You haven't entered credentials in DOMAIN\USERNAME format. Given value : $($Credential.Username)"
        }
     
        $DomainName = $Credential.username.Split("\")[0]
        $UserName = $Credential.username.Split("\")[1]
        $Password = $Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password
     
        $PC = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext([System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Domain, $DomainName)
        if($PC.ValidateCredentials($UserName,$Password)) {
            Write-Verbose "Credential validation successful for $($Credential.Username)"
            return $True
        } else {
            throw "Credential validation failed for $($Credential.Username)"
        }
    } catch {
        Write-Verbose "Error occurred while performing credential validation. $_"
        return $False
    }
}

$mycreds = Get-Credential

Write-Host "Adding $NewCompName to the domain"


Read-Host "Press enter to change computer name"

if ($renamecomputer -eq $true)
{Rename-Computer -NewName $NewCompName -DomainCredential $mycreds}
Read-Host "Press enter to restart computer"
Restart-Computer
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want something like this

```
if ($NewCompName -eq "" -or $NewCompName -eq $env:COMPUTERNAME) 
{
    
    $NewCompName = $env:COMPUTERNAME; $renamecomputer = $false
    
}
elseif($NewCompName -inotmatch "^DT|^LT")
{
  switch($computertype )
  {
    1{$NewCompNamePrefix = "DT"}
    2{$NewCompNamePrefix = "LT"}
    default{}
  }
  
  $NewCompName = $NewCompNamePrefix + $NewCompName
}
```

the `-inotmatch` is just making sure that if a `$newcompname` is inputted that already looks like `DTwhatever` or `LTwhatever`, it won't append an extra `LT` or `DT`

Unrelated (just me being a bit nitpicky):

Look into `Read-host -Prompt` and nest the prompts into do while loops, so you can validate that the input is what you're expecting.

something like this

```
$properChoices = @("a","b","c")
do
{
    $choice = (Read-Host -Prompt "pick a, b, or c").ToLower()
    switch($choice)
    {
        "a"{"You picked $choice"}
        "b"{"You picked $choice"}
        "c"{"You picked $choice"}
        default{Write-Warning "Invalid Input"}
    }
}
while($choice -notin $properChoices)
```